# Add Dynamic Header and Body in retrofit request

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit 2` and secure the API using Token Key
so I need to add the Token to request.

**here is my endpoint:**

```
http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/auth/queue/store
```

**POST request retrofit:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("auth/queue/store")
Call<ResponseBody> registerQueue(@Header("Authorization") String Authorization,@Part("task") RequestBody task);
```

**Activity:**

```
    public void sendNetworkRequest(String token, String task) {
    String temp ="Bearer "+token;
        RequestBody taskBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), task);
        Log.d(TAG, "send Network Request: Task: "+task+" "+" "+ temp  );

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.registerQueue(temp,taskBody);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SignUn Successful: ");
                    Toast.makeText(QueueActivity.this, "SignUp Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    onQueueSuccess();
                }else{
                    onQueueFailed(); // This is where the code ends and it doesn't add anything to API database
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG,"went wrong",t);
                Toast.makeText(QueueActivity.this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                onQueueFailed();

            }
        });
```

Error: there is no Syntax error. the problem is not being able to add anything to the backend.

P.S: on post man i can add achieve this by adding `Authorization: Bearer <token here>` in Header and request `task: <task here>` in `Form Data`
for example `task: mobile`

**UPDATE LOG**

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/LoginActivity: Login
D/LoginActivity: send request fired
D/LoginActivity: Log in Successfull: 
D/LoginActivity: this is token in intent: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4yMjo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDkxNTY3NDEwLCJleHAiOjE0OTE1NzEwMTAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MTU2NzQxMCwianRpIjoiYzRhMTM5YzkxZDBkZDNmMGM3MDUwMjI3ODc3YTQ5YmUifQ.9SA6D3O0oWd3fcg-i3lR2n1nbJ8r0Xj2wC3ZZ6I1l2k
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
V/RenderScript: 0xa9fbb000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa004f40
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa004b50
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa005090
D/QueueActivity: send Network Request: Task: mobiletest  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4yMjo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDkxNTY3NDEwLCJleHAiOjE0OTE1NzEwMTAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MTU2NzQxMCwianRpIjoiYzRhMTM5YzkxZDBkZDNmMGM3MDUwMjI3ODc3YTQ5YmUifQ.9SA6D3O0oWd3fcg-i3lR2n1nbJ8r0Xj2wC3ZZ6I1l2k
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa004fb0
```

** Update okHttpInterceptor LOG**

```
04-07 16:00:11.614 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/auth/queue/store http/1.1
04-07 16:00:11.614 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=958f2f27-e6d5-453b-836d-d2ef8073ef5a
04-07 16:00:11.615 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 232
04-07 16:00:11.616 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4yMjo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDkxNTY5OTkwLCJleHAiOjE0OTE1NzM1OTAsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MTU2OTk5MCwianRpIjoiN2ZmYWZhM2ZmMTJiOTM3Y2RhNmVkNjAyYzc4Zjk3ZWUifQ.JuOxvj80nr9LmjCvJqwSERmJD-jOtg_W9UHs232lEzY
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: --958f2f27-e6d5-453b-836d-d2ef8073ef5a
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="task"
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 6
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: mobile
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: --958f2f27-e6d5-453b-836d-d2ef8073ef5a--
04-07 16:00:11.618 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: --> END POST (232-byte body)
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found http://192.168.1.22:8000/api/auth/queue/store (185ms)
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Host: 192.168.1.22:8000
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Connection: close
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
04-07 16:00:11.804 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 13:00:12 GMT
04-07 16:00:11.813 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: {"error":{"message":"404 Not Found","status_code":404}}
04-07 16:00:11.813 24583-25144/com.example.comunicate D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (55-byte body)
```

Comment: Can you share the logs when you perform request?

Comment: @azizbekian Updated the Question

Comment: Use [okhttpInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) and share those logs.

Comment: @azizbekian you mean add the Header using Interceptor ?

Comment: No. Use `okHttpInterceptor`, which will log your network call in the `Logcat`. Then you'll be able to see what request you send to backend and what you received in the `Logcat`.

Comment: @azizbekian  added the log

Comment: Well, now you can see that you are actually sending the token. Perform a request with `Postman` and compare with the request you make from app, see the difference, and find out the issue.

Comment: ya thanks. in `Post` the  `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="task"` but as you can read in my description in question ex: im sending  the body with post man like `task` as name and `mobile`as value. isn't the same thing happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should intercept your requests and add the token in the header. Retrofit also supports re-authenticating, in case your token expires (which it should).
The following tutorial has all you need: [Retrofit — Token Authentication on Android](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android)

Comment: But why he can't do it with `@Header`?

Comment: @azizbekian Because the app might need to refresh the token. If you do it using the normal request header you will have to manage the failed requests. You would have to catch all the (401 - unauthorised), authenticate the user, get the new token and then retry the request. This is quite tricky to manage and Retrofit provides and elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, but assuming everything is ok with token, why can't he send with `@Header`? At the end of day, the question is why token is not being sent.

Comment: @EmanuelCanha I have seen the the Tutorial. they consider both ways in their blog. I added the `Interceptor`. i would appreciate your opinion

Comment: @Poorya Seems like your problem has nothing to do with the token.Your log shows a 404 which means your device is not able to reach the API endpoint

Comment: @EmanuelCanha well even with PostMan it comes back blank. but it will reach the API and add the record to database